# Take a bath or have a bath

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Yesterday my teacher corrected me, because I said "take a bath" (I was talking about taking a bath in the beach). He told me that the right way to say it was "take a dip". I want to know if he was right, or if that is only one way to say it.
Thank you all

Comment: Locale is as important as context; in the US, you are in fact **taking a dip**. **Taking a bath** is something else entirely; you are cleaning your body, generally by full-body immersion in a sufficiently large tub, plus soap.

Comment: It is curious, because my teacher is from UK. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Are you sure you mean *[bath](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bath_1)*? To *take a bath* or to *have a bath* is to immerse your body in water for washing or rinsing it; it is sometimes but not always interchangeable with *bathe*.

Comment: Thank you choster, I meant get into the water not to clean yourself, I am talking about get into the water to cool yourself.

Comment: "Take a dip" is one way to put it, but we don't **bath** in the sea, we **bathe**. Going on to **bathing** and **bathing**, although the same spelling, in BrE the ***a*** is pronounced in the same way as in the original verb.

Comment: @JoseSpanish This is why we ask that if you are confused about the use of a word, that you check the dictionary first and review the meanings. If you are new to Stack Exchange, I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster - "bathing" (from the verb "bathe") can also refer to swimming (or other in-water activity) at the beach; however, "taking a bath/having a bath" is as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not take a bath **in** the beach unless you meant a bath of sand. You could **bathe** (in the sea) **at** the beach.

> Bath noun
>   A1 [ C ] uk (us bathtub) a long plastic, metal, or ceramic
>   container that is filled with water so that you can sit or lie in it
>   to wash your whole body
>
> ​ A1 [ C usually singular ] the activity of washing yourself or
>   someone else in a bath

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bath

> bathe verb (SWIM)
>   [ I ] uk to swim, especially in the sea, a river,
>   or a lake

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bathe